# Starting Shrewsoft from a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, vpn

### Summary

**Connecting to Shrew soft vpn**
- terminal -- command works fine
- bash script -- same command returns error:

> "double free or corruption (out)"

### Problem

I often connect to my work vpn using the shrewsoft vpn client. I'd like to create a bash script so that I can use a single command to set up the vpn client, as well as a few other environment variables. When I run the command from the terminal, it works fine. But the same command in a bash scrip fails.

**Terminal Command**

```
ikec -r "<shrewsoft vpn connection name>" -u "john" -p "<password>" -a
```

**Bash Script**

```sh
#! bash
ikec -r "<shrewsoft vpn connection name>" -u "john" -p "<password>" -a
```

and then in the terminal I'm running the command:

```
> sudo bash ./vpn_connection.sh
```

I've already started "sudo /usr/sbin/iked". From the terminal, I can connect and disconnect successfully running that command, but when I run it from the bash script, I get an error.

Comment: `#! bash` is not a valid shebang. Needs to be an absolute path, as in `#!/bin/bash`, to allow invocation from a non-shell process -- though that's not the problem you're hitting right now.

Comment: Frankly, a double free *is a bug in the C code for the client*; you should be working with its authors (which is to say Shrewsoft in this case) on that. Though if you want to track down *why* the C code is taking different paths based on the invocation mechanism, I would get there by tracing syscalls and seeing where they differ.

Comment: ...one easy thing you can do is to compare the output of your working terminal command after a `set -x` with the line emitted by running `sudo bash -x ./vpn_connection.sh` and see if they differ. If, say, `-a` becomes `$'-a\r'`, then the problem is that you saved your script as a DOS text file instead of a UNIX one; but *any* difference would be informative.

Comment: BTW, if you don't use `sudo` when you're running the client straight from the terminal, why are you using sudo to run your script?

Comment: (Also, as an aside, putting a password on a command line is a Very Bad Idea -- command lines are public to every process on your operating system, including ones run by different/untrusted users; and even if the program obscures their content after it's finished starting up, there's still a window before that happens when they're exposed. Frankly, accepting a password that way gives me pause about how responsible/trustworthy the developers in question are).

Comment: Wow. A ton of useful stuff and shows me how much I still have to learn. Thanks. **1.** Fixed the #! location. **2.** I'll check the -x and see if there's any differences. **3.** The bash script originally also launched /usr/sbin/iked so I needed sudo. I removed that, but was still using sudo out of habit. **4.** I tried other vpn services and had even more trouble but am open to one I could get working. I understand its a PEBCAK issue.

Comment: Ok, I ran the script again without sudo, and it connects successfully. I tried using -x with sudo and not sudo to see the difference. With sudo it jumps immediately to "double free or corruption", so I don't see a way to trace back why that was a problem. Its great to have it fixed, **(THANK YOU)**, now I'm just curious why sudo broke it.

Comment: `sudo strace -f -s 2048 -o vpn_connection.strace bash ./vpn_connection.sh` will generate a syscall trace. Granted, reading/understanding that trace takes some background and experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your shell script runs, it loses any environment variables you defined but did not export.  When you run your script under sudo, sudo *clears* the environment except for a few variables.

It might be that that `ikec` relies on a missing environment variable, or perhaps that the `ikec` that's executed by the script isn't the same one, perhaps because of a PATH change, or alias.

I wouldn't use a script for this, by the way.  I would use an alias or a function.  In your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` (whichever you use) try:

```
alias vpn-connect='ikec -r "<shrewsoft vpn connection name>" \
      -u "john" -p "<password>" -a'
```

Then you can connect simply with

```
$ vpn-connect
```

However, the point made in the comments about passwords in files is well taken.  Look for a way to connect to your vpn without providing a password.  If you can't, you might just leave that option out of the alias, and let ikec prompt you for it.

Comment: Any particular reason to recommend an alias rather than a function? The quoting is more complicated, and there aren't really any compensating advantages.

Comment: No particular reason, no, although I didn't actually "recommend" it, just provided an example.  I guess I've used shells that didn't have functions, and did support aliases.  Agreed, the quoting is simpler with a function.

Comment: Functions are required for POSIX compliance (ever since 1992 publication of the POSIX.2 standard), whereas aliases are part of the optional user portability extensions. Thus, POSIX-family shells (those in the successor family to Bourne) are more likely to support functions than aliases.